# Installing Virtualbox on an Asus Chromebook

Tags: google-chrome, virtualbox

everyone. I have a question about Virtualbox. I am having trouble installing this application because I have an Asus Chromebook 202, and I can't find a favorable substitute to that application. Actually, I have tried to utilize the application called CrossOver, however I am only using the trial version.

Comment: This is not on topic for this website.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried follow these instructions to install the appropriate virtual box headers?  I believe they are not included by default.

https://techblog.jeppson.org/2015/11/install-virtualbox-on-a-chromebook/